# Syncfusion barcode control text doesnt appear at printing BMP VB NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, barcode, syncfusion

I have this code:

```
 Private Sub BuildCode()
    Dim barcode As String = TextBox1.Text + "%" + TextBox2.Text + "&" + TextBox6.Text + "*"
    'TextBox3.Text = barcode
    SfBarcode1.Text = barcode
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BMP = New Bitmap(GroupBox1.Width, GroupBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    'BMP.SetResolution(300, 300)
    GroupBox1.DrawToBitmap(BMP, New Rectangle(0, 0, GroupBox1.Width, GroupBox1.Height))
    Dim pd As New PrintDocument
    Dim pdialog As New PrintDialog
    AddHandler pd.PrintPage, (Sub(s, args)
                                  args.Graphics.DrawImage(BMP, 0, 0)
                                  args.HasMorePages = False
                              End Sub)
    pdialog.ShowDialog()
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pdialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
    pd.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    BuildCode()
End Sub
```

If i let the textbox1 control its printing the barcode. When I assing value to syncfusion barcode control, it build fine, it shows the barcode, but when I print instead of barcode is nothing.

What could it be?

Comment: Does BMP look valid: add PictureBox and set its image to BMP and .Refresh() it. It looks good? Maybe because image is 32bpp....printer can't really use 'alpha', try 24bpp. I don't know, just a guess.

Comment: all is fine with bmp. i really dont know what could be wrong. if i put textbox instead of syncfusion component and generate barcode by changing the font properities of textbox to a barcode font its printing the barcode. but as soon as i pass the value to sfbarcode1 doest print the barcode, although it shows the barcode correcly on screen. amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a workaround sample for exporting the Barcode as image and inserting the image to the group box and print the group box control for your reference, please refer the below code snippet and sample for more details.

```
   'initialize the barcode control 
    Dim barcode As SfBarcode = New SfBarcode() 

    'set the barcode symbology type 
    barcode.Symbology = BarcodeSymbolType.Code128A 

    'set the input text 
    barcode.Text = TextBox1.Text 

    'export the barcode control as image 
    PictureBox1.Image = barcode.ToImage(PictureBox1.Size)
```

Sample link: 
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/124890/ze/BarcodeVb1482679502

Could you please try this and let me know whether this meet your actual requirement.

Comment: hello. ToImage is not a member of SfBarcode. outputs this err. what could it be?

Comment: The barcode to image conversion support is available in latest versions (14.2.0.26) only, could you please update to the latest versions and get this support. 
   
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/latest-version